Why $C^2$ Boundary of a bounded domain in Euclidean space with nonpositive mean curvature is connected?
I am reading the paper UNIQUENESS, SYMMETRY, AND EMBEDDEDNESS OF MINIMAL SURFACES by R. Schoen. In the proof of Theorem 2 in the first section, the writter said that

Notice that the hypothesis that $\partial \Omega$ have nonpositive mean curvature implies that $\partial \Omega$ is connected.

Here $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain with $C^2$ boundary $\partial \Omega$.
I don't know how to show the connectedness under this nonpositive mean curvature assumption. I guess the argument may be like this:
If not, then the unit normal vector field has 'converse direction' at the 'outer component' and the 'inner component', thus the sign of mean curvature differs. But I cannot prove this.
Can some one help me?
